# Соединение по 2-ум полям возвращает меньше значений, чем нужно

Tags: sql, sql-server

В общем, есть 2 таблицы, которые я хочу соединить по 2-ум полям.

Пример запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.F=T2.F AND T1.F2=T2.F2
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Так вот, этот запрос мне вообще ничего не возвращает, хотя такие записи имеются.

Методом научного тыка я пришел к выводу, что это связано с тем, что поля по которым я произвожу соединение могут быть `NULL`.

Если я переписываю запрос таким образом:

```
     SELECT * FROM T1
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE T2.F1 IS NOT NULL 
AND T2.F2 IS NOT NULL) AS T2 ON T1.F=T2.F AND T1.F2=T2.F2
        WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

То возвращается ожидаемый результат. Подскажите, так это должно работать или первый запрос можно переписать без подзапроса, что бы было все четко?

Comment: Первый запрос не вернёт ни одной записи только в том случае, если каждой записи из T1 будет соответствовать хотя бы одна запись из T2 по соответствующим полям. Там у Вас точно LEFT, а не INNER? При Left join NULL не должен так влиять: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d9226/2

Comment: *я пришел к выводу, что это связано с тем, что поля по которым я произвожу соединение могут быть NULL* В какой из таблиц? Как вариант - продемонстрируйте это в тексте вопроса примером исходных данных и результатов (полученного и желаемого).

Comment: Что-то хрень какая-то. Сейчас все работает. Может быть я затупил поздно ночь...=( Или может быть MS SQL на большом кол-ве данных выполняет какие-то оптимизации => я не вижу проблем, когда пытаюсь повторить поведение на 5 тестовых записях.